# Drupal extra subdomains for some special nodes

Tags: hooks, path-aliases, .htaccess, subsites

I have the following in mind and I'm not sure how to realize it nicely.

1. Drupal 7 serves many nodes from several different taxonomies
2. If I visit a taxonomy page e.g. example.com/category-one/taxonomy-term-one I get a list of all the corresponding nodes
3. If I click on one of the list nodes, I get to the page example.com/content-type/node-name
4. There are some special nodes in this list, when I click on them, I get to the following special page node-name.example.com. This page is exactly the content like example.com/content-type/node-name but in this case, only the subdomain URL is accessible and example.com/content-type/node-name doesn't exist to avoid content duplication.

The first 3 items are easy standard tasks: The Pathauto module handles all the taxonomy url alias tasks etc.

The 4th item is my problem. My idea so far: The subdomain node-name.example.com just references a special folder under the drupal root, which contains some logic to determine the name of the node according to the subdomain. With the given subdomain I get the node id and just load all the stuff from drupals db with a service implemented for this usecase.

Questions:

1. Ist it possible to give a drupal node an absolute url alias like node-name.example.com just like node-category/node-name?
2. Are there any problems going to be concerning drupals $baseurl/site configuration?
3. As I'm editing everything just over the example.com/node/node-id/edit there should be no problems with the editing functionality, no?
4. What remains to be done?

Did anybody had to fulfill a similar apporach and could share some thoughts regarding my approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Domain Access](https://drupal.org/project/domain) module?

> The Domain Access project is a suite of modules that provide tools for
>   running a group of affiliated sites from one Drupal installation and a
>   single shared database. The module allows you to share users, content,
>   and configurations across a group of sites such as:
>
> - example.com
> - one.example.com
> - two.example.com
> - my.example.com
> - thisexample.com <-- can use any domain string
> - example.com:3000 <-- treats non-standard ports as unique
>
> By default, these sites share all tables in your Drupal installation.
>   The Domain Prefix module (for Drupal 6) allows for selective, dynamic
>   table prefixing for advanced users.

Basically you can assign a Node across any number of configured subdomains you've made drupal aware of.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I'm not sure if I should use this module. I don't want to share nodes across multiple subdomains, I want to replace the nodes url with the one special subdomain covering this node. So I want it to get listed under node-name.example.com and to be listed with this link under its category f.e. example.com/category-one/taxonomy-term-one. I don't want my whole drupal site to be available under node-name.example.com, I just want the one exact node page to be available there. If I take domain access, I get the whole stuff 'copied' and shared... Perhaps Global Redirect?

Comment: you can "share" the node(s) into any subdomain. You can share only 1 node, or any number of nodes to a domain. You may want to install it in a test setup locally and try it out for yourself for an hour or two. I believe Domain will also create the list of subdomain(s) the node is used in as well from the source domain.